# Laravel 4 : In nested relationship, how do I eager load and retrieve just the first/last data?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

```
A : User,
B : Conversations,
C : Messages
```

I want to get the **conversation together with it's most recent message** in an A->B->C relationship from A.

**Working relationships in model**

```
User belongsToMany Conversation
Conversation belongsToMany User
Conversation hasMany Message
Message belongsTo Conversation
User hasMany Message
Message belongsTo User

**note: User and Conversation are related to a many2many relationship connected 
by a pivot table
```

**I've tried**

```
$user->load(['conversations' => function($q)
            {
                $q->orderBy('created_at', 'desc');
                $q->with('Messages')->orderBy('created_at','desc');
            }]);
```

It nearly worked but it doesn't get the last message. Instead, it loads all of the messages belonging to that conversation.

**Unwanted result from above code**

```
array (size=7)
  'id' => int 90
  'name' => string 'haha,hehe' (length=9)
  'created_at' => string '2014-07-03 15:04:04' (length=19)
  'updated_at' => string '2014-07-03 15:04:04' (length=19)
  'microseconds' => string '1404370893302' (length=13)
  'pivot' => 
    array (size=2)
      'user_id' => int 1
      'conversations_id' => int 90
  'messages' => 
    array (size=27)
      0 => 
        ...
      1 => 
        ...
      ...
      26 => 
          array (size=7)
             'id' => int 816
             'user_id' => int 1
             'conv_id' => int 90
             'body' => string 'test1' (length=5)
             'created_at' => string '2014-07-03 01:13:35' (length=19)
             'updated_at' => string '2014-07-03 01:13:35' (length=19)
             'microseconds' => string '1404350015499' (length=13)
```

**Expected result**

```
array (size=7)
      'id' => int 90
      'name' => string 'haha,hehe' (length=9)
      'created_at' => string '2014-07-03 15:04:04' (length=19)
      'updated_at' => string '2014-07-03 15:04:04' (length=19)
      'microseconds' => string '1404370893302' (length=13)
      'pivot' => 
        array (size=2)
          'user_id' => int 1
          'conversations_id' => int 90
      'messages' => 
        array (size=1)
          0 => 
             array (size=7)
               'id' => int 816
               'user_id' => int 1
               'conv_id' => int 90
               'body' => string 'test1' (length=5)
               'created_at' => string '2014-07-03 01:13:35' (length=19)
               'updated_at' => string '2014-07-03 01:13:35' (length=19)
               'microseconds' => string '1404350015499' (length=13)
```

Comment: I don't see any legitimate usage where you'd put a `get` in a subquery (yes, that's a subquery, you should build the query there, not run it - that's what `get` does).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you put `get` (or `first`/`find` etc for that matter) in the closure it runs the query once more, but that query is ignored, and then Eloquent executes that query again:

```
$user->load(['conversations' => function($q)
{
   $q->orderBy('created_at', 'desc');
   $q->with('Messages')->orderBy('created_at','desc')
     ->get()  // this query is executed here
     ->first();  // this calls first method on the collection
     // but those 2 lines above take no effect with the eager load models
     // because Eloquent will execute the query again in the end
}]);
```

This is how you put constraints on the nested relation (**but it won't do the job here**):

```
User::with(['conversations.messages' => function ($q) {
  $q->orderBy(...)->where(...) ...;
  // but limit(1) can't be used here
}])->get();
```

`Limit` can't be used because it limits the whole set to 1, so there will be only 1 message returned in total. That said, only 1 conversation will have loaded single message in a collection.. Totally wrong

---

**So the only way to achieve this with `Eloquent`** is this 'helper' relation:

```
// Conversation model
public function latestMessage()
{
  return $this->hasOne('Message')->latest();
}

// then simply:

$user->load('conversations.latestMessage');

$user->conversations->first()->latestMessage; // single Message model
```

Comment: This indeed returns me the latest Message but I need to get **all of the User's** conversation **together** with its latest message. **Note:** There can be more than 1 conversation but each of those conversation will only have a single, latest message returned. So in short, I'm trying to return every Conversation related to a User together with the Conversation's latest message, not only the latest message in the conversation.

Comment: Uhm This does exactly what you needed: loads 1 latest message for each related conversation. It's the same as `$user->load('conversations'); $user->conversations->load('latestMessage')`

Comment: Well I tried it out but only got the latest Message without the conversation details. Also, I'm not sure whether this will return all conversations related to the user due to the use of first(). Correct me if I'm wrong. Anyway, I got it solved thanks to your help. ;)

Comment: You get all conversations here: `$user->conversations`, then `first` is just an example how to retrieve one particular conversation and its latest message. So yes, it does what you expect.

Answer (score 1):

Try using;

```
User::with('conversations', 'conversions.messages')
```

And with that you can add your eager loading contraints with a closure like;

```
User::with(array('conversations' => function(){}, 'conversions.messages' => function(){})
```

Be aware this is not tested.

Comment: This won't help in any way, because you can't limit the messages to 1 per conversation there.