# Laravel: Get column value from first() result of relationship query

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1, relationships

I'm trying to get a single column value from the first result of a Model's belongsToMany relationship query, as i'm returning the `->first()` result of the relationship I was hoping `$code->reward->title` would work but it doesn't.

I get an `Relationship method must return an object of type Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Relation` error

What I'm trying to do is the get the title of the *current* reward that is linked to a specific code - the `code_reward` pivot table has a `valid_from` and `expires_at` date as the reward linked to a code will change as time goes by, hence the need to get the currently active reward for that code.

Here's my code:

**Model: Code**

```
public function rewards()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Reward')->withPivot('valid_from', 'expires_at')->withTimestamps();
}



public function reward()
{
    $now = Carbon::now();
    return $this->rewards()
        ->wherePivot('valid_from', '<', $now)
        ->wherePivot('expires_at', '>', $now)
        ->first();
}
```

**Controller: CodeController**

```
public function index()
    {
        $codes = Code::all();
        return view('codes/index')->with('codes', $codes);
    }
```

**View: Codes/index**

```
@foreach ($codes as $code)

    {{$code->id}}
    {{$code->reward->title}}

@endforeach
```

Any help is really appreciated!

**Update**

Unfortunately both suggestions below (`$code->reward()->title` and `getRewardAttribute()` return an `Trying to get property of non-object` error.

If I remove `->first()` from the Code->reward() method and replace `$code->reward->title` with `$code->reward->first()` in the view it echoes out the whole reward model as json, however `$code->reward->first()->title` still returns the `Trying to get property of non-object` error

**Update 2**
If I do `{{dd($code->reward->title)}}` in the view I get the reward title but if I just do `{{$code->reward->title}}`, I don't!

AND the `$code->reward->title` works as expected in a `@Show` view, so could it be that the collection of codes supplied by the controller's `@index` method isn't passing the necessary data or not passing it in a necessary format??

**SOLVED**
The issue was caused by one of the `$code->reward`s in the `foreach` loop in the index view returning `null`! The first one didn't, hence the `dd()` working but as soon as the loop hit a `null` it crashed.
Once I wiped and refreshed the db (and made sure my seeds where adding only valid data!) it worked. Doing `{{$code->reward ? $code->reward->title : ''}}` fixed the issue. Grrr.

Comment: Can you post your controller method that is calling your Code model and passing the data to the view?

Comment: @AndyNoelker I have added that to the question too, also an extra note about moving `->first()` to the view, maybe that will help??

Comment: Hmm that is very strange. However, your update raised a few flags for me. Let's assume you leave the method name as `reward()`. Anytime you want to do _anything_ with that method, you need to include the parentheses. So when you removed `->first()` and made that call, it should have been `$code->reward()->first()->title`. Likewise, if you want to reference the actual relation you do not need the parentheses: `$code->rewards`. If that still doesn't help, can you try without the Carbon dates? Maybe this is a crazy formatting issue.

Comment: @AndyNoelker No luck with `$code->reward()->first()->title`

Also changed the method to 
`public function reward()
    {
        return $this->rewards()
            ->wherePivot('expires_at', '=', null);
    }` and no luck either :-(

Comment: @AndyNoelker, more weird behaviour, please see my **Update 2**...

Comment: Yeah, I'm pretty confused why `dd($code->reward->title)` works because calling it without the parentheses implies it's a relationship that should return a relation but it's actually a method that should return a Collection of models. Can you post the results of your `dd`? I'd be curious to see what it's getting returned as. If it's not an Eloquent object then that syntax won't work. Also, do you have some codes without rewards? Try wrapping your statement in `@unless($code->reward->isEmpty())` and `@endunless`. We have to figure out if this is a Blade problem or a logic problem.

Comment: And just to be sure, you have already tried `{{$code->rewards()->first()->title}}` right? It won't apply your valid/expiration filters but that should work otherwise.

Comment: Hi @AndyNoelker,  you were right with the `@unless` stuff, that was the problem, see my final note on the question. Thanks for you help man!

Answer (score 3):

Your statement is failing because `$code->reward->title` tells Laravel that you have defined a relationship on your Code model in a method called `reward()`. However, your relationship is actually defined in the method `rewards()`. Instead, `reward()` is a custom method on the model that you have made up. Calling it as a method and not a relation is the quickest way to get what you want.

```
{{$code->reward()->title}}
```

As @andrewtweber points out below, you could also make your custom `reward()` method into an attribute accessor. To do that, just rename the function to `getRewardAttribute()` and then you can call it in your view like you originally did.

Alternatively, you could get rid of that `reward()` method entirely and move all of that logic to the controller, where it probably makes more sense. You'd have to use constrained eager loading to pull that off. So in your controller you'd have something like this:

```
$codes = App\Code::with(['rewards' => function ($query) {
    $query->wherePivot('valid_from', '<', $now)
          ->wherePivot('expires_at', '>', $now);
])->get();
```

Of course, this would return *all* of your filtered codes. This is because you cannot apply a sql `limit` inside a nested eager relationship as [outlined here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24550295/laravel-4-in-nested-relationship-how-do-i-eager-load-and-retrieve-just-the-fi). So in your view, you would then have to do something like this:

```
{{$code->rewards->first()->title}}
```

However, it will be simpler to go with my first solution, so that's entirely up to you.

Comment: Or rename `reward()` to `getRewardAttribute()` and he can use it as `$code->reward->title`

Comment: Hi guys, thanks for the help, unfortunately neither of the first two options worked, I've updated the question, any idea why that might be?

Answer (score 0):

Try to set this method in Code Model, because query builder treats valid_from and expired_at as string, not date?

```
public function getDates()
    {
        return ['valid_from','expired_at'];
    }
```